# Numpy Pivot to dataframe but keep index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array that was created like this

```
npyieldData = np.empty((noScans,4, 3), dtype=float)
```

Once populated I would like to flatten this to a Dataframe with a layout like this.
I used x for the first dimension (noScans), y for the second (0-3) and z for the third (0-2)

```
Col_X        Col_Y         Col_Z0         Col_Z2         Col_Z3
-----        -----         ------         ------         ------ 
X-0_Value    Y-0-0_Value   Z-0-0-0_Value  Z-0-0-1_Value  Z0-0-2_Value
X-0_Value    Y-0-1_Value   Z-0-1-0_Value  Z-0-1-1_Value  Z0-1-2_Value
```

Here is a small array as sample

```
demo = np.empty((2, 2, 3), dtype=float)

demo[0,0] = [1,2,3]
demo[0,1] = [4,5,6]
demo[1,0] = [7,8,9]
demo[1,1] = [10,11,12]
```

The desired outcome would be

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
   0    0    1    2    3
   0    1    4    5    6
   1    0    7    8    9
   1    1   10   11   12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `ravel` and `reshape` the array (or just `vstack` as sammywemmy points out), and then create the first two columns, as an index, from a product of the shapes. Then reset the index and manually rename the columns.

```
x,y,z = demo.shape
df = (pd.DataFrame(demo.ravel().reshape((x*y, z)),
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(x), range(y)]))
        .reset_index())
df.columns = [f'Col{i+1}' for i in range(df.columns.size)]
```

---

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0     0     0   1.0   2.0   3.0
1     0     1   4.0   5.0   6.0
2     1     0   7.0   8.0   9.0
3     1     1  10.0  11.0  12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Build the dimensions frame and the demo frame independently, concatenate and generate the new column names

```
dimensions = (pd.DataFrame(np.argwhere(demo)[:, :-1])
              .drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True))
dimensions

    0   1
0   0   0
1   0   1
2   1   0
3   1   1

demo_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(demo))
demo_frame

      0     1       2
0   1.0     2.0     3.0
1   4.0     5.0     6.0
2   7.0     8.0     9.0
3   10.0    11.0    12.0

demo_frame = pd.concat([dimensions, demo_frame], axis="columns")
# same idea as @ALollz's
demo_frame.columns = [f"Col{i+1}" for i in range(demo_frame.columns.size)]
demo_frame


    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
0     0       0     1.0     2.0     3.0
1     0       1     4.0     5.0     6.0
2     1       0     7.0     8.0     9.0
3     1       1     10.0    11.0    12.0
```